¿Cómo cambiar estilos CSS en elementos HTML basados en la posición y contenido de dos arreglos en JavaScript?
Estoy desarrollando un juego en JavaScript donde el usuario debe adivinar una palabra. Tengo una serie de elementos HTML (cuadrados) que representan las letras de la palabra. Quiero cambiar el estilo de estos elementos basándome en la entrada del usuario y la comparación con la palabra.
código JS:
let existIndexArray = existLetter(wordArray, finalUserInput);
console.log(existIndexArray);
existIndexArray.forEach(element => {
squares[element].classList.add("gold");
});

let rightIndex = compareArrays(wordArray, finalUserInput);
console.log(rightIndex);
rightIndex.forEach(element => {
squares[element].classList.add("green");
squares[element].classList.remove("gold");
});

La función existLetter devuelve un array con los índices de las letras en la entrada del usuario que existen en la palabra objetivo pero no están en la posición correcta. La función compareArrays compara dos arreglos y devuelve los índices de las letras que coinciden en su posición.
Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo mejorar esta lógica para cambiar los estilos de los elementos de manera más eficiente? ¿Hay alguna mejor práctica para esto?

Debes agregar un [MCVE].
